# grub2 automatically select the first boot option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

### Here is what i did

I've installed Ubuntu 16 LTS after the Windows 7, and after a while updated to Windows 10

I haven't used the Ubuntu installation for a very long time

Upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS

After updating Ubuntu I've noticed after a while that the timer of 10s automatically disappears or (most of the times) doesn't appear at all, and won't automatically boot in 10s (I'd say over 30 minutes because I gave up waiting after that)

Finally after months with this issue:

I've changed `/etc/default/grub` from `0` to `4` (Windows position on grub)

Failed to make it work, since Windows 10 was automatically selected and then in a matter of seconds come back to the default Ubuntu.

I've installed grub customizer to try to change the order of Windows, it worked but the timer of 10s is actually an eternity (and disappear, just like after the Ubuntu upgrade)

Comment: Can you please try installing Boot-Repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yaron, sorry to tell you but it din't work, changed a little my boot tho, (there was some security mode boot for ubuntu, now it is all in the same option), nothing else

Comment: Win 10 has a 'fast boot' option that usually needs to disabled.  It should be in power options in windows.

Comment: fast boot semms to be a real problem for windows, but still the same problem :/